# eth.sign() never returns also does not call back

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, signature

(This is using local ganache, metamask set up to localhost which is working otherwise)

I am trying to establish how to sign, here is my code:

```
        async function sign()
        {
            console.log("sign func");

            let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
            console.log("account:", accounts[0]);
            let msg = "Some data";
            console.log("in data message:", msg);
            let prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + msg.length;
            let msgHash1 = web3.utils.sha3(prefix+msg);
            console.log("using hash:", msgHash1);

            let sig1 = await web3.eth.sign(msg, accounts[0]);
            console.log("signing...", sig1);

            //web3.eth.sign(msg, accounts[0]).then(console.log);

            let whoSigned1 = await web3.eth.accounts.recover(msg, sig1);
            console.log("WHO SIGNED", whoSigned1);
        }
```

(code is triggered via a button, works fine functionally aka it gets called)

All console logs until eth.sign happen just normal, correct account as well. Then metamask asks to confirm the signature, just like I would expect.

[image: confirm]

I click sign and thats it, nothing ever happens.
The function does not return, no further code is ever called. **Meaning it never calls back, it awaits forever.**
I also used then() syntax, same thing, never calls back.

If I do another transaction, while waiting, like minting an NFT, no problem goes through.

I switched metamask to rinkeby, same behavior. Switched it's mainnet, same. So I guess it's my code?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. As a workaround, I used `web3.eth.personal.sign` with the same arguments and omitted the `password` argument.

Comment: so it works even when you omit the password, hm. I mean thats the main issue with that function, you dont want to leak any keys.